# Using Elixir, how can I get the table object of a self-referential relationship to perform inserts on?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm using Elixir with SQLite and I'd like to perform multiple inserts as per the docs:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html#executing-multiple-statements

However, my ManyToMany relationship is self-referential and I can't figure out where to get the `insert()` object from. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easy if you just stick with SQL Alchemy's built in Declarative style instead of using Elixir as much of what it does is now doable in there.  Then you can follow the example here: [Many to Many](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Then look very closely at the code where a post is added and then keywords related to that post are added.  You get multiple inserts done for you into the relator table - the one that maintains the many to many relationship:

```
>>> post.keywords.append(Keyword('wendy'))
>>> post.keywords.append(Keyword('firstpost'))
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that mean I'd need to recreate my table, though? I should have done that from the beginning, but now I just want to perform some bulk inserts...

Comment: The table is the object that has the insert method on it.  You can get to the table object by referencing the class's "__table__" attribute.  For example skim through this [Another Tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/02/03/another-step-by-step-sqlalchemy-tutorial-part-2-of-2/) 
    
    # get a handle on the table object
    users_table = User.__table__